# Clustering big data

Tags: r, bigdata, cluster-analysis

I have a list like this:

A B score
B C score
A C score
......
where the first two columns contain the variable name and third column contains the score between both. Total number of variables is 250,000 (A,B,C....). And the score is a float [0,1]. The file is approximately 50 GB. And the pairs of A,B where scores are 1, have been removed as more than half the entries were 1.

I wanted to perform hierarchical clustering on the data.

Should I convert the linear form to a matrix with 250,000 rows and 250,000 columns? Or should I partition the data and do the clustering?

I'm clueless with this. Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your input data already *is* the matrix.
However hierarchical clustering usually scales O(n^3). That won't work with your data sets size. Plus, they usually need more than one copy of the matrix. You may need 1TB of RAM then... 2*8*250000*250000is a lot.
Some special cases can run in O(n^2): SLINK does. If your data is nicely sorted, it should be possible to run single-link in a single pass over your file. But you will have to implement this *yourself*. Don't even think of using R or something fancy.